# Xcode 8.3 - SourceKitService CPU 95%+ loads

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

Hi all iOS developer buddies, I updated my Xcode to 8.3 yesterday. And start from then, my MacBook fans kept running continuously. I opened 'Activity Monitor' and found that the `SourceKitService` took 95%+ to 130%+ CPU load. But I didn't even build my xcode project, I just opened it for code referencing (for Android).

Does anyone have any idea, how to tweak the settings to lower the CPU load?

Comment: Deleting the project `DerivedData` folder sometimes helps. (But you should first quit Xcode.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the problem and fixed it finally.

If you upgraded your Mac SSD(In my case, I brought a OWC Aura SSD for my late 2013 mbp.), you need to check if `TRIM` is enabled or not.

You can enable it by typing `sudo trimforce enable` in Terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Me too ~

When I encounter this problem.

I found that there are multiple threads `SourceKitService` .

Kill the `SourceKitService` thread that use CPU higher.

And then `clean` the xcode project and `clean Build Folder`.

solved

Answer (score 0):

This is not unusual, Xcode indexes your source files in the background when you open the project. If the CPU load did not stop, file a bug report on https://bugreport.apple.com and attach a sysdiagnose.